# Ruby on rails. Create 'model' from inside another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, controller, braintree

I have a 'job site' where users can create jobs and other users can apply for them. Users need 'tokens' to create jobs, and when they have none left are redirected to a purchase tokens page. The token system works fine.
I have set up a braintree form which works too, but doesn't create any tokens for the user. I want to create a new token(s) for the user when the transaction completes.

so far I have

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
resources :tokens
resources :transactions
```

Token.rb

```
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Transactions.rb

```
 class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

new token/payment form

```
    <form id="checkout" method="post" action="/transactions">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <h2 class="mbs">Transaction</h2>
  <p> Payment formfor one gig </p>
  <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
    <p>Please enter your payment details:</p>
    <div id="dropin"></div>
    <%=submit_tag "Pay €1.99", class: "button mt1" %>
  <%end%>
</form>
```

transactions_controller

```
 class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_user

  def new
  end


def create
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
              amount: 10,
              payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce])
    if @result.success?
      @user = Token.build(params[:user_id => current_user.id])
      redirect_to new_gig_path, notice: "Congraulations! Your transaction has been successfully!"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!"
      render :new
    end
  end

private
def generate_client_token
  Braintree::ClientToken.generate
end

def token_params
  params.require(:token).permit(:user_id)
end
def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
end
```

but I get an error 'Couldn't find User with 'id'='

The braintree clienttokens get generated in the tokens controller as the form is on the new token page. This works.

This is my last try at doing this but I have tried multiple ways of creating the tokens for the current_user but I cannot get it to work. 
The token model attributes are token_id and user_id.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the error? And what is the __exact__ error message?

Comment: Im sorry but I don't know what a stacktrace error is or how to retrieve it. I've only been usng rails for a couple of weeks. The error I get is:     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TransactionsController#create:  Couldn't find User with 'id'=  :  and ' @user = User.find(params[:user_id])' gets highlighted.

Comment: Then it appears that you don't pass `user_id` in your params. Fix that. Also use `Token.create` instead of `Token.build`

Comment: `Token.create(user_id: @user.id)` or `Token.create(user_id: current_user.id)` (depending on which user is actually meant to be there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
before_action :find user
```

and

```
def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

wern't needed.

Removing them and adding

```
Token.create(user_id: current_user.id)
```

has fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your before_action sets the @user using the parameters sent from the request.  before_action :find_user means regardless of the action within the TransactionController, before running any code, run the code in find_user.  In find_user, @user variable is set using request parameters.  Request parameters are those sent within the form or the query string.  A create method is called using a post action, which means the parameters should include all the properties within the form whose submit action was called.  In your form view, I see two nested forms.

With nested resources, like the route file above reflects, [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) on Rails Guides demonstrates the user_id is set by the path to the transaction submit.  That means your url helper for the form action needs to be `user_transactions_url(@user)`.  Essentially the form needs to direct to /users/[:user_id]/transactions

It may be easier to use Rail's form_for helper found [on the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).  This is a very complicated solution that has many things fundamentally wrong with them.  I've never seen anything like `params[:user_id => current_user.id]`  I'm guessing you are trying to do hash assignment inside of a lookup [Ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Two pieces of advice:

- Start with something simple
- Conform to Rails conventions

Happy scripting

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I realise that I have nested transactions which isn't necessary and have since removed it. I have been researching all afternoon various methods in achieving what I wanted, and have obviously made some mistakes. the "params[:user_id => current_user.id]" was something I found by searching and was a 'last resort', when I then posted the question. I am obviously new at rails, and I am interested to know what the "many things that are fundamentally wrong" are so I can identify and rectify these errors. I am currently cleaning up the code, but it DOES seem to work

Comment: I'm glad you chose to avoid the nested routes.  I recommend you put your user_id into the session, that way you don't need to pass it with every request.  Try out the `form_for` block it makes it easier to make forms.